# IndexOf & Substring extract the # into integer variable

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I have to ask for a birth date in form of dd/mm/yyyy, using the IndexOf and Substring methods extract the numbers into integer variables called day, month and year. I run my console and input 08/04/1995 it displays 08 days, 04 months and 19 years but I want it to display 08 days, 04 months and 1995 years

```
        string dateOfbirth;
        string temp;

        Console.WriteLine("Please enter a DOB in this form dd/mm/yyyy");
        temp = Console.ReadLine();
        dateOfbirth = temp;

        int length = dateOfbirth.Length;
        int index1 = dateOfbirth.IndexOf('/');
        int index2 = dateOfbirth.IndexOf('/', index1 + 1);

        string year = dateOfbirth.Substring(index2 + 1, length / index2 / 1);
        string month = dateOfbirth.Substring(index1 + 1, index2 / index1 / 1);
        string day = dateOfbirth.Substring(0, index1);

        Console.WriteLine( day + " day " +  month + " month " +  year + " year ");

        Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: Any reason you're doing this manually instead of calling `DateTime.ParseExact` or `TryParseExact`?

Comment: Specify your question/problem

Comment: @JonSkeet I guess this is homework.......

Comment: Why are you calling `IndexOf('-')` when you're asking the `/` as separator?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are truncating the year in your original code. So you need to change this:

```
  string year = dateOfbirth.Substring(index2 + 1, length / index2 / 1);
```

...to this:

```
  string year = dateOfbirth.Substring(index2 + 1);
```

The second parameter to [Substring](http://www.dotnetperls.com/substring) specifies how many characters should be returned. If you omit the second argument entirely, Substring will just return all of the remaining charaters (which works in this specific example).